# Can you use dynamic values in the instructions of a nested loop? and feedback on declaring variables (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested-loops

**Question Explanation** ([Zamka](https://open.kattis.com/problems/zamka)):
<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
*Input Example:*

```
100  
500  
12
```

**1st Line:** left bound **(L)**
**2nd Line:** right bound **(D)**
**3rd Line:** sum of digits within **N/M (X)**
<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
*Output Example:*

```
129 //focusing on this first
480
```

**1st Line:** minimal integer that = **X (N)**
**2nd Line:** maximal integer that = **X (M)**
<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
*Thought process:*
**1.** declare input values with an array:

```js
input = ['100','500','12'];
```

**2.** create loop between left (100) and right (500) bound:

```js
for (let i = input[0]; i <= input[1]; i++)
```

**3.** declare a sum variable = 0 within the loop:

```js
let sumMIN = 0;
```

**4.** create nested loop between 0 (first digit within `i`) and the length of `i` (`i.length`):

```js
for (let j = 0; j < i.length; j++) //problem => stops at i = 100
```

**5.** for every digit within `i` sum up to `sumMIN`:

```js
sumMIN += parseInt(i[j]);
```

**6.** if the sum of `i`'s digits = X then return true:

```js
if (sumMIN == input[2]) {
    console.log("true");
}
```

<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
*Problem:*
**1.** the nested loop only iterates `i = 100`
**2.** I think there is a problem lying within declaration of variables (**string** vs. **integer**)

**My Code so far:**

```js
var input = ['100', '500', '12'];

function decipher() {

    for (let i = input[0]; i <= input[1]; i++) { //loops executes correctly
        let sumMIN = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < i.length; j++) { //loop stops at i = 100
            sumMIN += parseInt(i[j]);
            console.log(sumMIN);
            if (sumMIN == input[2]) {
                console.log("true");
            } else {
                console.log("false");
            }
        }
    }
}

return decipher(input);
```

**Current Output:**

```js
1
false
1
false
1
false
```

*(let me know if you need more information!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback of peers and comments, I was able to find a solution:

```
var input = ['100', '500', '12'];

function decipher() {

for (let i = parseInt(input[0]); i <= parseInt(input[1]); i++) { //converted values to an integer
    var sumMIN = 0; //sets sum to 0 for every i
    var length1 = i.toString().length; //converts i to a string and finds the length
    var iString1 = i.toString(); //only converts i to a string
    for (let j = 0; j < parseInt(length1); j++) {  //converts length back to an integer
        sumMIN += parseInt(iString1[j]); //converts value to an integer to be able to do addition
    }
    if (sumMIN == parseInt(input[2])) { //converts value of 12 to an integer
        console.log(iString1);
        break; //stops when first "if" solution is found
    }
}

for (let i = parseInt(input[1]); i >= parseInt(input[0]); i--) { //goes backwards instead to find max
    var sumMAX = 0;
    var length2 = i.toString().length;
    var iString2 = i.toString();
    for (let j = 0; j < parseInt(length2); j++) {
        sumMAX += parseInt(iString2[j]);
    }
    if (sumMAX == parseInt(input[2])) {
        console.log(iString2);
        return;
        }
    }
}


return decipher(input);
```

Ouput:

```
129
480
```

I will probably do some tinkering within my code to make it more compact, but I am happy that I found a solution nonetheless. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop should just use `i` not `i.length`

Comment: I included `.length` because I am interested in the individual digits within the `i` value, not the `i` value itself. Example; i = 100, j < i.length (which is 3)

Comment: @doroshm If you iterate over it as a number (100) then it will go to 100. If you iterate over the string "100" it will convert the string to its unicode values which is not 100. You could convert to a number for j but compare the length as a string (e.g. `i.toString().length == input[2]`)

Comment: @Dr-Vortex - How can `i` be both a string that has a `.length` and be something you can do `i++` on?  That does not make sense?  What exactly is the value and type of `input[0]`?

Comment: @jfriend00 You could have `i` as a number which would loop correctly. Then using `i.toString().length` would give you the number of digits of `i`. I believe the inputs are strings though you could ask the OP  for clarification.